# How do I Add field from lookup table to repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using a repeater to display some content. I have a lookup table with Guids as the reference but I want to be able to display the lookup value. I am using the entity framework.

So my questions is

1. How do i get the property description from the lookup table of payment status using ef.
2. How do i display a count within the panel title to reflect the amount of items be it returned.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPayments" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>Payment 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Payment Agreed
            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("agreedPaymentsPerMonth") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                    <br />
                    Payement Date
            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("paymentDate") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
                    <br />
                    Make A Payment
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Make a Payment"></dx:ASPxButton>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

And in my get data function as follows:

```
public List<tblPortalPayment> getUserPayments(Guid recordId)
{
    List <tblPortalPayment> _payments= portalEntities.tblPortalPayments.Where(a=>a.userId== recordId).ToList();
    return _payments;
}
```

My EF Diagram.

[image]

Comment: I assume that you meant to post code rather than xaml for the first image?

Comment: its not xaml why would i post the code for the ef dirgram when i said diragram

Comment: I only asked because you posted the same html twice in the post. The only difference being that the second contains `</asp:Repeater>` at the end.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane please see the modified code. I removed the duplication thanks very much for pointing that out mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your entities, so that the `paymentStatus` Property in `tblPortalPayment` is a reference to `tblPortalStatus`

Assuming that the relationship is 1-1, you should then be able to access the property as `<%# Eval("paymentStatus.description") %>`

Your ef diagram should look something like this;
[image]

Alos, for the count, take the count of the objects returned by your method and store it as a property in the code behind, then reference that member.

Comment: Hi i treid that but its the field code that it needs to link to but it said that is was not a unique key /.